# Как получить объект canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Ellipse
                 Width="30"
                 Height="30"
                 Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Canvas Name="canvas1"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
         </Style>
     </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ItemsControl>
```

**В этом коде xaml вывожу все объекты Shapes на Canvas, но не могу получить ссылку на Canvas с именем canvas1 в коде C#**

Comment: Ответ - никак. Вы не должны вообще хотеть в C# коде руководить UI контролами. Вот у вас привязана коллекция `Shapes` (в которой должны быть простые классы!), вот ей и руководите, нужно что-то еще из кода - создали свойство, привязали, готово. Но дергать UI из C# - забудьте.

Comment: Я изучил ваши предыдущие вопросы и понял зачем вам это. Смотрите в чем дилемма... По правилам MVVM вы не должны ничего знать про UI, это является грубым его нарушением, а это значит, что вы не можете передать в VM слой объект `Canvas`. (про это я и писал выше). За работу с диском (а вам надо сохранить снимок на диск) отвечает Model слой. И вот тут проблема, вам надо как-то и что-то передавать из View в Model, чтобы тот уже это сохранил, но вот что- вопрос, ибо `RenderTargetBitmap`  - это View, а сохраняет он в поток или можно в `Bitmap`, и вот в теории их уже можно передать в Model

Comment: Передавать как параметр команды, конвертируя предварительно `Canvas` в `Bitmap`. НО, и тут подвох, ибо стандартный `IValueConverter` будет просчитывать размеры канваса только при инициализации, а значит это не самый лучший вариант... Короче, у вас весьма сложный вопрос) Как и вопрос про получение `ItemsPanel`, ибо вы не можете просто так взять из визуального дерева объект, вам надо [перебирать все дерево](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744947/6808809), в надежде, что там будет что-то нужное. Так что, удачи вам))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ всё-таки такую кучу информации стоит оформлять ответом, а не пачкой комментов.

Comment: @aepot Это догадки, а не ответ, причем те, которые могут быть мимо. Ну а сам вопрос - дубликат предыдущего от автора, с той-же просьбой и даже код одинаковый, + автор не особо хочет объяснять что именно он хочет. Поэтому, как-то писать ответ мне не особо хочется.

Comment: Девочки не ссорьтесь, я нашёл решение)

Comment: @thebrokenblow "Девочка", раз нашла ответ, то стоит его оформить. Не забывайте, SO это не форум, а сайт, где сообщество собирает полезные вопросы и ответы на них, где информация должна иметь пользу не только вам (автору), но и будущим читателям. Сейчас ваш вопрос из разряда "вот код, хочу это", польза в чем? Добавляйте ответ, будет хоть что-то, даже может научите меня как сделать правильно, ибо я чет вчера пытался сделать по правилам MVVM скрин канваса, так и не смог, будет интересно глянуть на подобное решение.

Comment: Согласен про девочку лишнее было). Задача была следующая получить изображение canvas. Вообще можно mvvm опустить им же можно не на 100% следовать и на canvas подписать событие loaded и получить canvas из sender, код будет ниже. Что касается mvvm, то во view model у нас храниться список Shapes с некоторыми данными и средствами c# можно рисовать фигуры https://c-sharp.pro/общие-замечания-классы-graphics-pen-и-brush/.

Comment: @thebrokenblow Отходить от MVVM конечно можно, да вот только не желательно. MVVM это про "Разделение", а не про тесную связь UI и кода. Вот и ожидал от вас такое увидеть, а на деле увы, даже не отвечает на вопрос, который вы сами и задали, ибо это больше на обходной путь похоже, чем на решение) Но, дело ваше конечно.

Comment: Ну это пока временное решение, вбудущем реализую вышеописанную идею, ожидайте)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void LoadedCanvas(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas = (Canvas)sender;
}

<Canvas Loaded="LoadedCanvas" Cursor="{Binding Cursor}" Focusable="True"
ClipToBounds="True" IsItemsHost="True"/>
```